# SQL - how to join 3 tables and select the count of many columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck in this situation and don't know how to write the select query that results to what I want. here is the situation

I have 3 tables session, request, log

**session table**

```
# session table to store sessions data
ID     user
------------
1      John
2      Sarah
```

**request table**

```
# request table to store `http` requests come to me
ID     session
------------
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      2
6      NULL
```

**log table**

```
# log table to store the logs that I record in my php code and store_
# them in the database while processing the requests 
ID     request
------------
1      1
2      1
3      2
```

---

**What I want** is to select each session and the number of requests made in this session and also it's number of logs. I want the result to be

```
#sessions result
+----+-------+----------+------+
| ID | USER  | requests | logs |
+----+-------+----------+------+
| 1  | John  |    4     |  3   |
+----+-------+----------+------+
| 2  | Sarah |    1     | NULL |
+----+-------+----------+------+
```

---

**What I do** is I use joins and group by session Like

```
select session.*,count(request.id) as requests,count(log.id) as logs
from session left join request on session.id=request.session
left join log on request.id=log.request group by session.id
```

the problem is when I do this , if 1 request has more than 1 log, it will be duplicated by the join like request 1 in our situation which has logs 1 and 2

```
# wrong result !! not what I want. notice the count of requests in session 1
+----+-------+----------+------+
| ID | USER  | requests | logs |
+----+-------+----------+------+
| 1  | John  |  ((5))   |  3   |
+----+-------+----------+------+
| 2  | Sarah |    1     | NULL |
+----+-------+----------+------+
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

*thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select session.*,count(DISTINCT request.id) as requests,count(log.id) as logs
from session left join request on session.id=request.session
left join log on request.id=log.request group by session.id
```

Comment: what can I say ? DISTINCTTTTTTTTTT  thank you very very much

Answer (score 1):

Just try to catch my approach. I haven't compile query.
I need to highlight this one

```
(select count(*) from log where request.id=log.request)
```

Full SQL

```
select session.id,session.user,count(request.id) as requests,logs from (
 select session.*,(select count(*) from log where request.id=log.request) as     
logs from sesson join
request on sesson.id=request.sesson group by request.id
)group by session.id
```

Comment: thank you sir for your time , I will try your approach